# All of my image and sknodes are in the wrong position with different iphones

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, constraints

So i was extremely happy today to finally finish my first app, i got it all ready for the app store and was very close to submitting it for review. What I didn't realize though is that my app looks and runs perfectly in iPhone 5 Xcode simulator.. but when i switch it to iPhone 6 and 6 Plus.. EVERYTHING is off balance and it looks like a 2nd grader tried to make an app.. Any tips on sizing my app to be more universal? like fit all iPhone screens.

FYI: I'm using Swift in Xcode and everything is programmatic, not on storyboard.

Thank you, any help will be very much appreciated.

This is how I'm positioning my SKNodes..

```
    sunIcon = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Sun-icon")
    sunIcon.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(frame) - 5, y: CGRectGetMaxY(frame) - 220)
    sunIcon.zPosition = 49
    addChild(sunIcon)
```

Comment: Also if you need me to upload any code, I will, but i'm not quite sure that will help

Comment: Use Auto-layout and size classes for your app, otherwise set frames for your controls with respect to different screen sizes :)

Comment: okay ill give it a whirl, thank you @AmanAggarwal

Comment: Take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2)

Comment: If you're using spriteKit, neither of those suggestions will be much help.

Comment: I am @beyowulf, what can i do?

Comment: How are you setting the position and size of your nodes? Post the code for that.

Comment: @Bliitzkr3ig You are saying that this is happening on simulator, right? Note that you should test your apps on real device. Simulator tests are irelevant, and most of the times not accurate. For example, even if everything looks fine on simulator it doesn't mean it will work on an actual device (and vice versa).

Comment: Okay, maybe I am a bit harsh about simulators. They are not sooo bad, and will give you similar results in compare to what you are going to see on a real device. But you can't rely on that because nobody will play your game on a a simulator. Also, performance seen on simulator is not realistic and simulators should be used just to give you a basic idea about how your app will look on a certain device.

Comment: @beyowulf I've added code to a simple skpritenode i have positioned

Comment: @Whirlwind I completely understand what you mean, I should not just rely on the simulator alone. Therefore, I have tested them on real devices as well. The results were a bit different but both the simulator and the devices showed off-balance results.

Comment: For SpriteKit, you should really test on a real device. The simulator can behave quite differently from a real device! It's mostly "worse" on the simulator than on a real device, but there are issues the other way around (you may get surprises with z-ordering).

Comment: Could you give a brief explanation of how this node, or other nodes, is/are "off balance"? Is it its size or position? If you just want general tips, they're mostly like don't hard code values. If you've written a lot of code like node.position  = CGPoint (20.0,110.0) that's bad. You should make your positions relative to the bounds of the scene, etc.

Comment: @beyowulf how exactly do i make my positions relative to the bounds of the scene, And to answer your question, they are off balance because of the positioning, the sizing is all okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem with making it universal for multiple phone sizes could be that your scene size is the same no matter what phone you run it on. The size is taken from the GameScene.sks file and is not changed when you run on a different phone. This means that (0, 0) might not be the bottom left corner of the screen. This can make it hard to program it to be universal. If you want the scene.size to be different depending on the phone, just change the size of the scene before switching to it in the GameViewController or where ever else you might switch to a new scene. This can be done by doing something like this while creating the new scene before you transfer to it:

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
scene.size = CGSizeMake(screenSize.width, screenSize.height)
```

This wont magically make the app universal, but it can be very helpful when programming it to fit on all sizes. Also keep in mind different types of scaleModes, like AspectFill which is the one I use when changing the size of the scene.

Comment: You were correct that it wasn't magic but it definitely aligned a lot of the screen, Thank you Callum

Answer (score 0):

In general it is best to avoid hard coding spite locations. For example saying something like

```
node.position = CGPoint (103.3,142.0)
```

Is not likely to scale well on different screen sizes. It might be the appropriate position on the iPhone 5, as it is at a third of the width across and fourth of the height up the screen, but on the iPhone 6 it will likely look off, as it's closer to a fourth the width across and a fifth the height up the screen. It is better to say something like:

```
node.position = CGPoint(self.frame.size.width/3,self.frame.size.height/4)
```

Thus the node will be in the same position relative to the view's dimensions.

If you have already hard coded positions, and the layout looks good for the iPhone 5 you can use a function like:

```
func relativePointWithPoint(point:CGPoint)->(CGPoint)
{
    return CGPoint(x: point.x/320.0*self.frame.size.width, y: point.y/568.0*self.frame.size.height)
}
```

To translate the point into it's relative position. For example:

```
node.position = self.relativePointWithPoint(point:CGPoint (103.3,142.0))
```